# How to multiline and left adjust in an equation

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I'm trying to make a set of equations look neater, but need to go onto the next like and left adjust, as shown here:

[image]

This is what I have so far, I've just filled with \quad but I dont think it looks very clean:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned} 
        \label{eq:model-3-intercept+time}
        q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} + \alpha_{rs}t + \gamma_{rs}drug) \quad \text{for } (r,s) \in \{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)\} \text{ where } \gamma_{23} = \gamma_{34} \\ \\
        q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} + \alpha_{D}t + \gamma_{D}drug) \quad \text{for } (r,s) \in \{(1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)\} \\ \\
        q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} + \alpha_{B}t)  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \enspace \text{for } (r,s) \in \{(2,1), (3,2), (4,3)\}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ‘left adjust’?

Comment: Ah sorry - I mean, when I go onto the next line, I want the text to be on the left. Exactly like in the first image where the 'for' starts under the main equation. Does that help?

Comment: All lines beginning with ‘for’ have to be vertically aligned?

Comment: yes - exactly it :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional, for Times Roman text and math font
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:model-3-intercept+time}
\begin{aligned} 
   q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} + \alpha_{rs}t + \gamma_{rs}\mathit{drug}) \\
             &\qquad\qquad\text{for $(r,s)\in\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)\}$, 
              where $\gamma_{23} = \gamma_{34}$} \\[1ex]
   q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} + \alpha_{D}t + \gamma_{D}\mathit{drug}) \\
             &\qquad\qquad\text{for $(r,s)\in\{(1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)$\}} \\[1ex]
   q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} + \alpha_{B}t)  \\
             &\qquad\qquad\text{for $(r,s)\in\{(2,1), (3,2), (4,3)\}$}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
        \label{eq:model-3-intercept+time}
        q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} & & + \alpha_{rs}t + \gamma_{rs}\text{drug})\\
          & & & \text{for } (r,s) \in \{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)\}, \text{ where } \gamma_{23} = \gamma_{34} \\[0.5ex]
        q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} & & + \alpha_{D}t + \gamma_{D}\text{drug})\\
          & & & \text{for } (r,s) \in \{(1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)\} \\[0.5ex]
        q_{rs}(t) &= \exp(\beta_{rs} & & + \alpha_{B}t) \\
         & & & \text{for } (r,s) \in \{(2,1), (3,2), (4,3)\}
    \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]